# Classes of maps with good a-priori bounds

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-equations

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the closed unit disk and let $u: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth embedding. We say that $u$ is a harmonic map if $\operatorname{Tr}(\nabla d u)=0.$

Basic question: If $u$ is a harmonic map, can one deduce a priori bounds on the diameter of $u$ in terms of its boundary value?

Broader question: I am looking for a class of geometric equations on maps $u: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ whose solutions satisfy a priori estimates in terms of their boundary values.  In particular, if I fix $C:= u(\partial \mathbb{D}),$ is there a class (or classes) of maps which would allow me to bound the diameter of $u$ in terms of $C$?

I know very little Riemannian geometry and realize that my question is both vague and open-ended. I would be grateful for any type of answer, including reading or reference suggestions.

EDIT: after reading Anthony Carapetis's comment, I realized that it was a mistake to state my question in terms of maps into $\mathbb{R}^n.$  I assumed that this would make the question simpler without fundamentally changing the answer, but the maximum principle provides an answer which seems unique to $\mathbb{R}^n.$  In fact, what I am really looking for is a class of maps $u: \mathbb{D}^2 \to N^n$ admitting a priori bounds on the diameter in terms of boundary data (e.g. the diameter of the boundary).

Comment: Harmonic maps into $\mathbb R^n$ have harmonic components, so the maximum principle should give you a direct bound. Maximum principles also apply to nonlinear equations so there should be a fairly wide class of examples - e.g. anything of the form $a^{ij}(x,u,\ldots)D_i D_j u^\alpha = 0$ with $a^{ij}$ elliptic should work identically.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.  As it happens, I was looking for an answer which would generalize to arbitrary Riemannian manifolds, so it was a mistake to state the question only for maps to $\mathbb{R}^n.$ I have now edited the question.

Comment: My intuition is that such a bound should be possible (for harmonic maps at least) when $N$ has non-positive curvature, though I'm not 100% sure. There are two approaches I can think of: the first is to compose $u$ with an isometric embedding $N^n \to \mathbb R^k$ and attempt to apply the maximum principle directly to components (or to $|u|^2$, etc.). The difficulty here is that you will get extra terms involving the second fundamental form of the embedding. Alternatively, apply the maximum principle to bound the derivative of $u$ and then estimate $|u(x)-u(y)| \le \|Du\||x-y|$.

Comment: I'm rustier than I should be on harmonic maps. I'd have a look in the literature for examples of bad harmonic maps into positively curved spaces to see if you can find a counterexample. My intuition comes from the lower-dimensional case of geodesics: in hyperbolic space you get such a diameter bound, but on the sphere you do not. The connectedness of the boundary could make things better, though.

Comment: Thanks for these helpful comments. I appreciate you sharing them.